# Slick Slider not working in AngularJS app

Tags: html, angularjs, slider, slick.js

I've added all scripts and css, it is working when the html page alone runs, but not when the app runs. Nothing is showing in the console. I've tried adding css and js references in index page too.

What may be the problem?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.5/slick.min.css'>
 <div class="slider responsive">
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="" />
                </div>
    </div>


<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.5/slick.min.js'></script>

<script src="js/slider.js"></script>

<script>
 $(function () {
 $('.slider').slick();
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention its an angularjs App, but I dont see angularJS referenced in your HTML. If you want an angularJS version of slick carousel, please check this out:

http://devmark.github.io/angular-slick-carousel/#/

Let me know how it goes.

Note: This should have been a comment , but answering as I dont have enough points to comment.